# En México, ¿cuál es la frase más utilizada para referirse a un gran contenedor de plástico en el que la gente deposita la basura?

Tags: sustantivos, méxico

- bote de basura
- receptáculo de basura
- basuradora
- basuradería
- barril de basura
- caja de basura
- contenedor de basura

Tenga en cuenta que el dialecto del español que se usa en México es diferente al dialecto del español que se habla en España.

Estoy interesado en la palabra "receptáculo de basura" que usaría una persona nacida y criada en México.

En la misma línea, estoy buscando una frase para《depósito de basura》 utilizada por miembros de la clase trabajadora, no la frase utilizada por la aristocracia.

Comment: Los aristócratas no nos preocupamos de eso, así que no sabemos si existe un término para ello.

Answer (score 1):

En México, la frase más comúnmente utilizada para referirse a un gran contenedor de plástico en el que la gente deposita la basura es "bote de basura". Esta expresión es ampliamente conocida y utilizada en todo el país, y se refiere tanto a los contenedores grandes que se encuentran en la calle como a los más pequeños que se utilizan en hogares y oficinas.

Es importante destacar que en diferentes regiones de México, especialmente en áreas rurales o en comunidades indígenas, se pueden utilizar diferentes términos para referirse a los contenedores de basura. Por ejemplo, en algunas áreas se puede utilizar la palabra "tambo" o "tambor" para referirse a un contenedor grande de basura. Sin embargo, "bote de basura" es la expresión más comúnmente utilizada en todo el país.

Answer (score 0):

La voz más utilizada en México es "**bote de basura**", seguida de cubo, tacho y contenedor de basura.

Es significativo que a la acción de "**tirar la basura**" se le llame también "**botar la basura**".

"**Receptáculo de basura**" es todo aquel "**recipiente**" que recibe o donde va a parar la basura, desde una papelera, "cubo", "tacho", "bote de basura", contenedor.

**P.D.** Un posible sustituto en voz mexicana tanto de la palabra "recipientes de basura" como "depósitos de basura",  podría ser "**Tachos de basura**"

https://listado.mercadolibre.com.mx/tachos-de-basura